How to "Query" All Emails Sent in SFMC Over the Past Year
Thank you in advance for your help.
I need your opinion on the process for retrieving all emails sent over the year, retrieving the name of each email, and related subscriber's email reciepients (up to 10k by send)
Some information: We have 10,000,000 sends per Business Unit and 4 Business Units in total. Emails from journeys are included. We have cart abandonment, welcome journeys, etc., but also newsletters.
Here is the process I initially had in mind:
Retrieve the sends through Intelligence Reports and export the report (since I cannot access data older than 6 months in Data Views).
Manually retrieve the subscribers who received each send by navigating to Email Studio > Reports > Sends.
This represents an enormous investment in terms of time and doesn’t seem very smart either. Perhaps there’s an SSJS endpoint to retrieve this data.
Thank you all
A fellow SFMC user :)

I would suggest using tracking extracts to export historical data over 6mths
